# Meaning of this even as

Tags: meaning

I am not able to understand the meaning of **this even as** in the following sentence

> This even as fresh cases were generally dropping due to reduced spread of the then dominant strain.

[Click here To Read The Full Article](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/england-in-lockdown-on-rapid-spread-of-covid-19-variant/article33504233.ece?homepage=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "this" refers to what was stated in the previous sentence:

> Based on an analysis of cases and genome sequences of nearly 44,500 samples collected from England between September 21 and December 13, it was found that even during the previous lockdown, *the new variant spread in many locations*. *This even as fresh cases were generally dropping due to reduced spread of the then dominant strain.*

Some words are elided, and the sentence is equivalent to:

> This **[happened]** even as fresh cases were generally dropping due to reduced spread of the then dominant strain

So **this** refers to **...the new variant spread in many locations**.

The word **even** is an intensifier, and the word **as** is equivalent to **at the same time as**.

The general sense of the passage is contrasting the fact that a new, more contagious variant was still spreading though new cases were dropping.